# Searching within an array of strings

Tags: php, string, preg-match

Ok, I'm feeling retarded here,

I have a string like so:

```
$string = 'function module_testing() {';
```

or it could be like this:

```
$string = 'function module_testing()';
```

or it could be like this:

```
$string = 'function module_testing($params) {';
```

or this:

```
$string = 'function module_testing($params, $another = array())';
```

and many more ways...

And than I have an array of strings like so:

```
$string_array = array('module_testing', 'another_function', 'and_another_function');
```

Now, is there some sort of `preg_match` that I can do to test if any of the `$string_array` values are found within the `$string` string at any given position?  So in this situation, there would be a match.  Or is there a better way to do this?

I can't use `in_array` since it's not an exact match, and I'd rather not do a `foreach` loop on it if I can help it, since it's already in a `while` loop.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `foreach` loop here is the appropriate solution. Not only is it the most readable but you're looping over three values. The fact that happens within a `while` loop is a non-issue.

```
foreach ($string_array as $v) {
  if (strpos($string, $v) !== false) {
    // found
  }
}
```

You can alternatively use a regular expression:

```
$search = '\Q' . implode('\E|\Q', $string_array) . '\E';
if (preg_match('!$search!`, $string)) {
  // found
}
```

There are two parts to this. Firstly, there is the `|` syntax:

```
a|b|c
```

which means find `a`, `b` or `c`. The second part is:

```
\Q...\E
```

which escapes the contents. This means if your search strings contain any regex special characters (eg `(`) then the regex will still work correctly.

Ultimately though I can't see this being faster than the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Well, in this case it's only 3 values, but this is actually not always guaranteed to be the case...

Comment: what about `stristr`, would that be helpful?

Comment: @SoLoG `strstr()` isn't much different to using `strpos()` in this case.

Comment: Ok, Yeah, I suppose the foreach loop is needed here.  Would a for loop be even faster?  If I did a `count` on it first?

Comment: Don't worry about differences between `for` and `while` loops. That's micro-optimization and is an irrelevant distraction. Readability is *far* more important (and any differences are going to be insignificant anyway).